# How can I trigger a function when any of the function under a class is called?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a dunder method than triggered when any of the function under a specific class (including the function from its parents) is called?

Let's look at a small example:

```
class SpecialClass(ParentClass):
    def NormalFunction1(self):
        print('Function 1.')

    def NormalFunction2(self):
        print('Function 2')

    def SpecialFunction(self):
        print('Triggered.')

cls = SpecialClass()
cls.NormalFunction1()
cls.NormalFunction2()
```

The output I want is:

```
Triggered.
Function 1.
Triggered.
Function 2.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Cleanest way is with a decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/198633

Comment: No, I can't. The class is inherited from a built-in class. (I forgot to mention in the question xD)

Comment: Would you be able to subclass it and call `super().funcName()`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Subclass `SpecialClass`. Then let tell `getattribute` to `print("Triggered")` before calling the function from `SpecialClass`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!!! For an additional question, how to trigger it after calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Thanks to @inspectorG4dget!

```
class SpecialClass():
    class SubClass():
        def NormalFunction1(self):
            print('Function 1.')

        def NormalFunction2(self):
            print('Function 2')

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == 'SubClass':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        print('Triggered.')
        return self.SubClass().__getattribute__(item)

cls = SpecialClass()
cls.NormalFunction1()
cls.NormalFunction2()
```